# Multiple inner joins to get a single record by sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have tables like this.

`Title` table:

```
Book_Title        | ISBN    |Publisher_ID
--------------------------------------
Engineering BK    | 1234556 | 1
Time for a change | 1233333 | 2
Digital Fortress  | 2132312 | 3
Davinci Code      | 2314234 | 3
Angles and Demons | 1232323 | 3
```

Book ISBN is not normal ISBN it's  of `int` type.

`Publisher` table:

```
Publisher_ID  | Publisher_Name
--------------------------------
       1      | Crt Books
       2      | NAD Books
       3      | Corg Books
```

`Authorship` table:

```
Author_ID | ISBN
---------------------
   1      |  1232323
   1      |  2314234
   1      |  2314234
```

`Author` table:

```
Author_ID | Author_Name
------------------------
     1    | Dan Brown
```

`Copy` table:

```
   Copy_ID   | ISBN 
-----------------------
      1      | 1234556
      2      | 1233333
      3      | 2132312
      4      | 2314234
      5      | 1232323
      6      | 1232323
```

`Loan` table:

```
Borrower_ID   | Copy_ID | Date_Borrowed |Date_Returned
------------------------------------------------------
     1        |   1     |  2014-10-20   | NULL
     2        |   2     |  2014-10-18   | NULL
     3        |   3     |  2014-10-11   | 2014-10-20
     1        |   4     |  2011-11-11   | 2011-11-25
     2        |   5     |  2010-10-10   | 2010-10-20
     4        |   6     |  2012-12-12   | 2012-12-20
```

Status of the books which are not returned yet are SAVED as NULL.

I want to select the Title_Names of the books of which a single copy of the Title hasn't been borrowed in the last 365 days.

I implement it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   (T.Book_Title) AS BookTitle,
   COUNT(CP.Copy_ID) AS NumberOfCopies,
   MAX (LN.Date_Borrowed) AS LastlyACopyBorrowedDate
FROM Title T INNER JOIN Copy CP ON T.ISBN=CP.ISBN
INNER JOIN Loan LN ON CP.Copy_ID=LN.Copy_ID
INNER JOIN Authorship ASP ON T.ISBN=ASP.ISBN
INNER JOIN Author AT ON ASP.Author_ID=AT.Author_ID
INNER JOIN Publisher PB ON T.Publisher_ID=PB.Publisher_ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,Date_Borrowed, GETDATE()) > 365
GROUP BY (T.Book_Title);
```

This works fine.

But I cannot get the Author_Name and the Publisher_Name of the title.

When I modify it to get the Publisher Name and the Author Name like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   (T.Book_Title) AS BookTitle,
   COUNT(CP.Copy_ID) AS NumberOfCopies,
   MAX (LN.Date_Borrowed) AS LastlyACopyBorrowedDate,
   AT.Author_Name,
   PB.Publisher_Name
FROM Title T INNER JOIN Copy CP ON T.ISBN=CP.ISBN
INNER JOIN Loan LN ON CP.Copy_ID=LN.Copy_ID
INNER JOIN Authorship ASP ON T.ISBN=ASP.ISBN
INNER JOIN Author AT ON ASP.Author_ID=AT.Author_ID
INNER JOIN Publisher PB ON T.Publisher_ID=PB.Publisher_ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,Date_Borrowed, GETDATE()) > 365
GROUP BY (T.Book_Title);
```

It gives me an error saying:

> Column 'Author.Author_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How to solve this?

Comment: @@Sahil all columns of select statement which are not part of aggregate function should be in "Group By" clause, Add all three columns in group by like GROUP BY T.Book_Title, AT.Author_Name,PB.Publisher_Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AA_SC hinted it should be as follows:

```
SELECT
  T.Book_Title AS BookTitle,
  COUNT(CP.Copy_ID) AS NumberOfCopies,
  MAX(LN.Date_Borrowed) AS LastlyACopyBorrowedDate,
  AT.Author_Name,
  PB.Publisher_Name
FROM
  Title T
  INNER JOIN Copy CP ON T.ISBN = CP.ISBN
  INNER JOIN Loan LN ON CP.Copy_ID = LN.Copy_ID
  INNER JOIN Authorship ASP ON T.ISBN = ASP.ISBN
  INNER JOIN Author AT ON ASP.Author_ID = AT.Author_ID
  INNER JOIN Publisher PB ON T.Publisher_ID = PB.Publisher_ID
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(DAY, Date_Borrowed, GETDATE()) > 365
GROUP BY
  T.Book_Title,
  AT.Author_Name,
  PB.Publisher_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add the add to your `Group By` Clause

`GROUP BY
  T.Book_Title,
  AT.Author_Name,
  PB.Publisher_Name`

Remember, you are using `COUNT` and `MAX` for the other columns, then, you need GROUP by the others columns, in this specific case: `T.Book_Title, AT.Author_Name, PB.Publisher_Name`.

You can read a little more about [aggregate functions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)